# sanity check, current distribution

Tags: power-supply, power, design

This is a really basic question I know, I am just doubting myself for some reason.
I am trying to make a power distribution board. I have a 12v power supply rated to 20A.

If I arrange my DC Jacks in the following way:
[image]

If have devices requiring 2A supply connected to J1 - J5 and devices requiring a 1A supply J6-J13 my total would be 18A giving me a 90% load?

Have I got my maths/layout right, with the layers of parallel sockets?

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: For reliability , you might want to insert 2A PTC protection from shorts into each jack as they are cheap.  But Yes 90%. You could use more Jacks with the assumption some jacks may be using less than rated current if supply has OCP, OTP.  This is how USB hubs work with 8x 2.4A,5V jacks but limited to 65W or so.

Comment: aah yes, fuses!

thankyou.

Comment: i think your math is right. There is no need in a schematic layout to resemble the physical realitiy, so, you could have drawn all connector pairs (J6 and J7, etc) like J1 and J2. However, as you drew it, makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

That all looks fine at a basic level but you must bear in mind that a short on any one of the loads will pull a current only limited by the supply and the cable resistance.

[image]

*Figure 1. A selection of PTC fuses from LittleFuse.*

You should probably protect each socket with a resettable fuse. See [LittleFuse PolyFuse Selection Guide](https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/resettable_ptcs/ec327-e_polyfuse_ptc.pdf) for a well written introduction to the topic.